# How to run a process in Java synchronously?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I want to run process synchronously without it resorting to asynchronous run.

Consider the code

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(COMMAND);
LOGGER.info(String.join(" ", COMMAND));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process cmdProces = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmdProces.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) System.out.println("tasklist: " + line);
cmdProces.waitFor(); // (1)
LOGGER.info("Script executed ");
// Java reference to output file of COMMAND
```

This code snippet is inside a scheduler that executes every 30 seconds. The the next execution is preformed before the previous run is finished. I checked the documentation and it says

> The subprocess is not killed when there are no more references to the
>   Process object, but rather the subprocess continues executing
>   asynchronously.

Now I would say that my script `COMMAND`  is still running but java interprets it as having no more reference. How can I prevent this? That it is forced to wait until `COMMAND` is finished? There is a output of `COMMAND` that shows that the script is finished. Is it possible to wait for this output? Or is this rather unfavorable?

Comment: not clear what you want. Please explain what is wrong with the code you published - why it does not behave as you want.

Comment: `cmdProcess` is a reference to the `Process` object. As long as you are in the `waitFor()` method, that reference still exists.

Comment: I added the detail that this code is inside a scheduler that runs the code every 30 seconds. And in most instances the next execution is made before the previous one is finished.

Comment: If you want to launch successive subprocesses and only launch one subprocess after the previous one has terminated, then why launch them at 30 second intervals? Method `waitFor()` suspends the `Thread` it is called on until the subprocess terminates. So why not make a simple loop. Each iteration launches a process and waits for it to terminate.

Comment: Because the call every 30seconds checks if there is new data to run the script on. So that if there is no now data the subprocess is not run

Comment: if scheduler runs the code next time but the previous process still works, what do you want: to wait the previous process to finish, or completly refuse to start next process?